# Sending a HTTP Post Request with LotusScript

Tags: http, http-post, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to send a HTTPS Post Request to a server. The content should be a JSON Expression.

For LotusScript I have not found a solution. A code snippet which solves the problem is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is through LS2J or if your client runs on windows, you could use the xmlhttp object an example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881896/vbscript-download-webpage-html)